# How can I float right a div of inline-flex without using float?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to ***avoid float*** (or find an alternative) to move the `toolbar div` to the right of the page while keeping its size the size of its contents.

So, if I simply added:

```
  float:right;
```

To the below `.toolbar` I would have what looks like what I want, which is basically a container that takes up the SIZE of its items (from `display:inline-flex`) that is aligned to the right of the page.

However, I don't want to `float` it to the right (It works, but I hear you should avoid it and I am looking for an alternative to float).

I did try using `margin-left: auto;` but couldn't figure that one out (unless I took off the `flex:inline-flex` which I need for the parent size.

Any thoughts?

```css
.page {
  padding: 20px;
}

.toolbar {
  background: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.item {
  background: azure;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
}

.switchbox {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="toolbar">
    <div class="item switchbox">Switchbox Component</div>
    <button class="item button">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make your parent .page display: flex and justify-content: flex-end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flex properties to align elements along the horizontal or vertical axis.

To enable flex properties, simply make the parent a flex container.

Add this to your code:

```
.page {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```css
.page {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 20px;
}

.toolbar {
  background: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.item {
  background: azure;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
}

.switchbox {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="toolbar">
    <div class="item switchbox">Switchbox Component</div>
    <button class="item button">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can do this:

```
.page {
  display: flex;
}

.toolbar {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```css
.page {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
}

.toolbar {
  margin-left: auto;
  background: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.item {
  background: azure;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
}

.switchbox {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="toolbar">
    <div class="item switchbox">Switchbox Component</div>
    <button class="item button">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

More details: [Understanding `justify-content` and `auto` margins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Comment: Excellent. It was the second that I needed (so that the rest of the page remained left justified). Or I could have just wrapped that toolbar in another div and done the first. Thank you for the great snippets. Oh, and the reason the margin-left trick wasn't working was that I didn't have flex on page. Again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add this:

```
.page {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```